# Localhost error Fuseki-service Ubuntu

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki, tdb

We've installed [Fuseki2](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/index.html) as a service at a Ubuntu-server and its works fine:

`sudo service fuseki status
 * Fuseki is running with pid: 915`

I now can go to *http://xyz:30303/manage.html* (where *xyz* it the ip-address of the server) and it shows the Manage datasets screen, but nothing happens when I click *add new dataset*.

Console browser (and also *http://xyz:3030/$/server*) gives "*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Access denied : only localhost access allowed)*"

How do I configure this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default security, using shiro, limits access to localhost. You can find information on security configuration here http://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-security.html and examples in the default shiro.ini

Answer (score 2):

shiro.ini

### and the rest are restricted to localhost.

/$/** = localhostFilter <- **change to 'anon'**