# Can not upload RDF files via webinterface from remote computer (only localhost)

Tags: jena, fuseki

I would like to use the apache-jena-fuseki server to provide an ontology within a local network environment. And as such it should be editable from all machines in the LAN ideally via a webinterface (for simplicity).

The built-in **webinterface** of **apache-jena-fuseki** is doing that job well, BUT only from the machine running the server. Accessing the webinterface from other machines will somehow not provide the functionalities of managing (uploading & deleting) the **datasets**.

Is this a configuration issue? And, if yes, how and where should it be modified?

Any help on the matter is highly appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: This is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200342/localhost-error-fuseki-service-ubuntu . See the links in the answer there for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the config in shiro.ini solved the problem!